# Bluetooth Audio: A2DP duplex mode does not work

Tags: audio, bluetooth, pipewire

I am failing to get my Logitech H800 headset's mic to work at a better quality than "HFP/CVSD" 8kHz and would like to find out whether it's an intrinsic hardware problem or a config problem.

I'm using pipewire/wireplumber on Ubuntu 22.04.

`pactl list cards` shows (tried to remove non-relevant lines):

```
Card #7776
    Name: bluez_card......
    Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        [...]
        api.bluez5.icon = "audio-headset"
        api.bluez5.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_44_73_D6_3B_9D_D0"
        bluez5.auto-connect = "[ hfp_hf hsp_hs a2dp_sink ]"
        bluez5.profile = "off"
        device.alias = "H800 Logitech Headset"
        device.api = "bluez5"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.description = "H800 Logitech Headset"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        [...]
    Profiles:
        a2dp-sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 16, available: yes)
        headset-head-unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
        a2dp-sink-sbc: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec SBC) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 20, available: yes)
        a2dp-sink-sbc_xq: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec SBC-XQ) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 19, available: yes)
        a2dp-sink-faststream: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec FastStream) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 18, available: yes)
        a2dp-sink-faststream_duplex: High Fidelity Duplex (A2DP Source/Sink, codec FastStream) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 17, available: yes)
        headset-head-unit-cvsd: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP, codec CVSD) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 2, available: yes)
    Active Profile: headset-head-unit-cvsd
    Ports:
        headset-input: Headset (type: Headset, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "headset"
            Part of profile(s): headset-head-unit, a2dp-sink-faststream_duplex, headset-head-unit-cvsd
        headset-output: Headset (type: Headset, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "headset"
            Part of profile(s): a2dp-sink, headset-head-unit, a2dp-sink-sbc, a2dp-sink-sbc_xq, a2dp-sink-faststream, a2dp-sink-faststream_duplex, headset-head-unit-cvsd
```

As you can see, `a2dp-sink-faststream_duplex` claims: `sinks: 1, sources: 0` . However, the `ports` below say that both the input and output are part of the `a2dp-sink-faststream_duplex` profile.

`pactl list sources` shows:

```
Source #8162
    State: RUNNING
    Name: bluez_input.......a2dp-sink
    Description: H800 Logitech Headset
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 16000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        api.bluez5.a2dp-duplex = "true"
        api.bluez5.codec = "faststream_sbc"
        api.bluez5.profile = "a2dp-sink"
        api.bluez5.transport = ""
        card.profile.device = "0"
        device.id = "144"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.bluez5.a2dp.source"
        node.autoconnect = "true"
        device.description = "H800 Logitech Headset"
        node.name = "bluez_input.......a2dp-sink"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        priority.driver = "2010"
        priority.session = "2010"
        factory.id = "8"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        device.api = "bluez5"
        media.class = "Audio/Source"
        node.latency = "512/48000"
        media.name = "H800 Logitech Headset"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "split"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "126"
        object.serial = "8162"
        client.id = "56"
    Ports:
        headset-input: Headset (type: Headset, priority: 0, available)
    Active Port: headset-input
    Formats:
        pcm
```

which looks weird, since even though it is the input/mic/source, it shows `profile = "a2dp-sink"`.

Is there anything I can do to fix this or am I stuck using this headset in HFP/CVSD "tin can phone" mode?

Comment: can this headset work in duplex mode?